# Pattern matching in Rust with multi-type pattern to match to

Tags: rust

I am working in a research group and we currently have some code that is written in ocaml and we working on converting it to rust to improve runtime (I am brand new to rust). What I am doing is taking a propositional logic formula in the form of a string and trying to convert it into qcir formula. An example would be "a /\ b" as a string being converted into the string "and(a,b)". What we are doing in ocaml is having custom types for literals such as a and b, ops such as AND( /\ ), and expressions such as a /\ b.

The problem now is that I have recreate these types in rust. What I currently am doing is creating an enum for the operators and structs for the literals and expressions. Now, what I want to do is use match on a string like the one mentioned above and have the matching values be a concatenation of multiple types, rather than just strings since the literals will be changing throughout the formula. The format I want to achieve for now is super basic, something like this

```
function defintion(s: String) {
   match s {
      // example for AND, parentheses just for clarification
      concat!(literal (a, struct) | operator(/\\, enum) | literal(b, struct) , rest@..) => and(a,b)
   }
}
```

Like I already mentioned, I have no idea if you can concatenate different types into a string to match like that in rust. I found some methods online that may require using a parser and lexer, however that method may be too complex for my knowledge on rust. Any assistance on how I could achieve something like this would be great.

Comment: I think it might help if you posted a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The pseudo-Rust syntax is tripping me up a little.

Comment: Will the names `a` and `b` appear in the string literally, or are those potentially _expressions_ such as `(a \/ b) /\ (c \/ d)`?

Comment: @MatthieuM. As of right now I was just trying to see if I can get it to work with no expressions and just a /\ b, but once I got that working I need to expand it to expressions as well. It will end up taking entire formulas and work from the inner most parentheses outwards and one of the patterns to match to would be a string like (expression /\ literal) or (expression /\ expression).

Comment: @isaactfa Do you mean an example of the formula that I would be trying to break down?

Comment: @pshevchen: You presented some form of "ideal" syntax you'd want to try and make work in your question. Unfortunately, noone but you has an idea what that syntax is supposed to do in the first place, making it _really_ hard to understand what you are trying to do. What are `literal` and `operator` are supposed to do? Only you know. Although, to be clear... I think you're heading into a wall. It seems to me that you'll need a full-blown parser, and that's unlikely to fit into a single `match` statement.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Gotcha. I'm still new to stack overflow and not great at asking questions in a manner that helps everyone understand. I don't think I will expand further because it seems like you answered my question with the mention of the full blown parser and that may just be a little to big of a task to take on to try to make this work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @pshevchen: No worries. Asking questions is an art in itself -- it's really hard to find the balance between providing enough information and not providing too much, and even harder to understand which information _you_ know (from the context, from your background, ...) is both necessary and likely unknown to others :) With regard to parsers, Rust has parser combinator libraries that you can find on crates.io. See https://crates.io/keywords/parser-combinators. If you don't plan on further elaborating, I advise you to close/delete your own question to avoid "bloating" the site.

Comment: Not sure if this would qualify as a full answer or not; there's lots of ways to write a parser, but if you're a fan of `match` and patterns you can use [slice patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#slice-patterns) on a vec of tokens, which can work reasonably well as a simple parser. [Here's an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=baf65e2f0eb852f1cd963bb5d1a3ac5e).